# onLongPress и swipe в ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, swipe, gestures

У меня есть ViewPager с фрагментами, у каждого фрагмента есть GestureListener, в GesterListener я отлавливаю onLongPress, но в тоже время, когда происходит swipe между фрагментами, то это тоже считается за onLongPress, как сделать так, что бы swipe не считался, как onLongPress?

```
 private class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                Log.i("Swipe works", "!!!");
                boolean result = false;
                try {
                    float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                    float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                        if (Math.abs(diffX) > 100 && Math.abs(velocityX) > 100) {
                            if (diffX > 0) {
                                Log.i("Swipe right", "!!!");
                            } else {
                                Log.i("Swipe left","!!!");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return true;
            }


            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

 imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.placeholder));
ChildFragment.loadBitmap(ArrayFilepaths.get(pos).getPath(), imageView, mPager.getCurrentItem(), x, y);
                int x;
                int y;

                 int downY = 0;
                 long downTime = 0;

                switch (e.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        downY = (int) e.getY();
                        int downX = (int) e.getX();
                        downTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                        int upY = (int) e.getY();
                        int upX= (int) e.getX();
                        long upTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();


 float deltaY = downY - upY;
                        float deltaTime = upTime - downTime;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        Log.wtf("Action move works", "!!!");
                        int moveX =(int) e.getX();
                        int moveY =(int) e.getY();
                        long moveTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();


                        if  (moveTime-downTime > 25)  {
                            Log.i("Events ", "onLongPress works");
                            x = (int) e.getX();
                            y = (int) e.getY();
    }
    }
    }
    }
```